# I am getting this error when importing pymqi -> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pymqe: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pymqi

I have set the environment variables (LIB, INCLUDE, MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH), pymqi installed successfully with pip yet I am getting this error:

```
$ C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe d:/workspace/myproject/app/python/mq-writer/src/mq_writer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymqi\__init__.py", line 132, in <module>
    from . import pymqe # type: ignore
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pymqe: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\workspace\myproject\app\python\mq-writer\src\mq_writer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymqi
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymqi\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import pymqe # type: ignore # Backward compatibility
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymqe'
```

I have downloaded and redirected my MQClient libraries to C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
as mentioned in [How to install pymqi in window 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281909/how-to-install-pymqi-in-window-64-bit)

I followed the troubleshooting portion of https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/How%20to%20install%20Python%20IBM%20MQ%20module%20PyMQI%20in%20Linux%20and%20Windows_2.pdf and ran *set-visual-studio-env.bat*

After doing this, I am still getting this error stated above. Is there anything else I need to do in order to use pymqi with the MQClient libraries or troubleshoot on windows?

Using:
Python-3.10.11
pymqi-1.12.10